# Is it possible to 'source' the output of a python script

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a large python codebase that knows a lot about my working environment. I would like to use it to set up my ZSH session when i open a terminal window.  The python script would output text that exports variables, defines functions / aliases etc.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
./myPythonScript -outputZSHSettings | source
```

but it does not seem to. Is there any way to do something like this? I suppose I could write everything to a temp file, source that, then delete the file, but that seems clunky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bash and zsh you can use Process Substitution:

```
source <(./myPythonScript -outputZSHSettings)
```